# Can't build project java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have an Android project I created in Android Studio and it worked fine. Recently, I've started using IntelliJ IDEA and when every time I want to build my project, I get the following exception:

```
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

```
Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.ServiceLoaderLite.loadImplementations(ServiceLoaderLite.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension$loadProcessors$efficientProcessorLoader$1.doLoadProcessors(Kapt3Extension.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorLoader.loadProcessors(ProcessorLoader.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorLoader.loadProcessors$default(ProcessorLoader.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.loadProcessors(Kapt3Extension.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:171)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:384)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:375)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:159)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:442)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1013)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1055)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1012)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:441)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 49 more
```

I tried every other solution on the net but none worked (yes, I have JDK8 checked in my Gradle settings).

How can I make it work with IntelliJ?

Some info:
MacOS Catalina
IntelliJ Version 2019.3
JDK 1.8 update 212
Kotlin plugin: 1.3.61-release-IJ2019.3-1

Comment: did you add apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so I found and fixed the problem.
JDK location wasn't the same.

In Android Studio it is something like:
`/private/var/folders/4f/h8xs1k2501j67y1vf24sh2pr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F6163339-3902-4A3C-9086-0E9F7A4EE908/d/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`

In IntellJ, it was `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home`

I copied Studio's JDK path to IntelliJ and it worked.

(You can change it in the `Project Structure` dialog (CMD + ; on Mac))

Comment: Likewise...  I brought project from another machine.  Just resetting File->Project structure->Sdk Location->JDK location to what other projects on this machine are using fixed t3he problem.  Heck of a vague error message though...